# Cgi/perl scripts display as code in Monterey

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

These scripts worked fine prior to upgrading to Monterey!
I have followed the tutorial from “etresoft” regarding editing the `httpd.conf` file and restarting Apache, but when executed the Perl script (code) displays in Safari. The scripts live in my `Sites` directory, and execute properly when run from there.

There are a suite of cgi/perl scripts that function to manage and present a family budget.
The first script opens a data file that contains various accounts: expenses (like groceries, utilities, etc.) and incomes. The script presents an HTML file with a large table, each line in the table documents an account, how much is due, and when. The script allows you to edit the various values. From this table page it is possible to call another script which will present those accounts due for the month and calculate the total amounts owed and the total incomes and the difference.

These are the edits made to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

Enabled the php and perl:

```
LoadModule php_modul/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
 <FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
 </FilesMatch>
LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
```

Uncommented the `LoadModule` for `userdir_module`:

```
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
```

Uncommented the `Include` line for `httpd-userdir.conf`:
User home directories

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

Saved the `httpd.conf` file.

This is the edit made to `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`:

Uncommented the `Include` line for `*.conf`

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

I edited `/etc/apache2/users/<your short user name>.conf`. It now looks like this:

```
<Directory "/Users/rjklaus/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    AddHandler perl-script .pl
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.php
    AllowOverride None
    Require host localhost
</Directory>
```

From a “Terminal” window I ran the following command:

```
chmod +a "_www allow execute" ~
```

I ran `apachectl configtest` and received a “Syntax OK”.

I next entered `http://localhost/`  into the Safari address bar. I did NOT see the “It works!” that I was told to expect. Instead I got:

```
/Users/rjklaus/Ray's%20Stuff/HTML%20Budget/test.pl
```

“HTML Budget” is a file (not a directory) in a subdirectory of “Ray’s Stuff”. The text string “test.pl” is not in that file. Test.pl is a short perl script in my Sites directory.

I am running perl v5.30.3 from /usr/bin/perl.

There are three versions of Apache2 located in /Users/Shared/ subdirectories labeled:
Previously Relocated Items,
Previously Relocated Items 1, and
Previously Relocated Items 2.

Comment: Make sure the files have the execute permission. Other than that, it's probably a problem with your apache config, and we can't help you because you provided neither your config nor any information about the files (location, extension). And also because this isn't the right site for asking help configuring apache. One of the sister sites is more appropriate.

Comment: You should provide the examples of what you're doing.  Show your httpd.conf (or at least the relevant section for running CGI scripts) and show the commands you are using to start and stop apache.  Try some other experiments, like changing the home directory in the httpd.conf, restarting Apache, verifying that those changes are in fact working.

Comment: This is the edit made to /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf:

Uncommented the Include line for *.conf

Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf


Edited /etc/apache2/users/<your short user name>.conf. It now looks like this:

<Directory "/Users/rjklaus/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    AddHandler perl-script .pl
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.php
    AllowOverride None
    Require host localhost
</Directory>

Comment: Please don't dump all of that hard-to-read information in comments. Instead, edit your question and add the information there (formatted to be as readable as possible).

Comment: Thanks. I have deleted the comments and augmented the original post to contain the information in a (hopefully) more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure, the cgi_module is enabled?

```
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgid_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    LoadModule cgi_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
```